# upload large file in php

Tags: php

How can I upload files larger than 2MB in PHP,I searched the Internet and i changed the `php.ini` file,the line is: `"upload_max_filesize = 200M"`,but I still can't upload even 2 MB file.

What seems to be the problem?

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What your `can't` means? Can you be more specific? Any errors from error_log would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you running on a shared host or is this on your local machine?

Comment: There are **LOADS** of questions about this on Stack Overflow. Did you do a search?

Comment: I am running in single system

Comment: @Emmerman: Cant means i cant get the  output.

Comment: @karthick: What does "can't get the output" mean? You need to be _much_ more specific, please. Describe **precisely** what you see, and what steps you took to see it.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal:My problem is:I have if loop in my php code,if file is successfully uploaded means get message as success otherwise not,first i tried files upto 1 MB all i got is success,after i tried to upload 17MB file,got not.I searched in net and changed php.ini file,Still i cant uploadthat 17MB file..

Answer (score 10):

Once upon a time I'm facing this problem with my WAMP server, and when I search for solution, I stumbled upon to this discussion. So, if someone have the same problem, this is my working solution, I hope this help:

1. I'm using WAMP stack. By reading your comment above, you are using WAMP stack too. In case you don't know, WAMP server has 2 (two) php.ini (in PHP directory and Apache directory) configuration, one for CLI and the other for Apache itself ( see [php.ini on WAMP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446832/wampserver-why-is-the-stack-installed-with-2-php-ini-files) ). So, I create info.php to detect which php.ini use by my server, and in my case that is the one in Apache directory ( see [Which PHP Ini file does my WAMP webpage uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528212/which-php-ini-file-does-my-wamp-webpage-uses)).
2. Open your php.ini ***that used by your server***, and as @Pascal Martin suggested, change `upload_max_filesize`and also set `post_max_size` then restart your server.
3. Check again your info.php, make sure the value of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` has changed to your desired value.
4. Restart Apache.

It's worked for me, hope this help.

Answer (score 4):

As you guessed, you have to set [**`upload_max_filesize`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)...

But **you also have to set [`post_max_size`][2]** *(quoting)* :

> Sets max size of post data allowed.
>
> This setting also affects file
> upload. To upload large files, **this
> value must be larger than
> `upload_max_filesize`**.

Comment: What does `phpinfo()` indicate ?

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN:PHP Version 5.2.6

Comment: @karthick What does phpinfo() indicate **for these values**?

Comment: @karthick so, you're editing wrong php.ini. What does phpinfo says about loaded php.ini? which one you editing? **did you restart your server**?

Comment: @karthick: Did you forget to restart Apache?

Comment: So, you probably didn't change the php.ini file which is used by your webserver -- check which php.ini file is really used : it should be indicated at the beginning of the ouput of `phpinfo()`. And restart Apache when you've done modifications to php.ini

Comment: @Col.Shranpnel: I changed php configuration file,In my wamp dir i dont have .ini file.

Answer (score 1):

There are also other options which could limit this:

```
max_input_time = 600
php_value max_execution_time = 600
post_max_size = 200M
```

(...and restart Apache)

Comment: I change the value of:                                 php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
php_value post_max_size 60M
php_value max_execution_time 500
php_value max_input_time 500

Comment: what does max_execution_time do here?

Comment: max_execution_time is used for maximum life time of the script and the time that the script should spend in accepting input

Comment: @karthick PHP script being called by web-server only AFTER the file finished uploading.

Answer (score 1):

get your php.ini-dist file,

- edit it to set proper values shown above
- rename it to php.ini
- copy it in WINDOWS directory
- restart Apache

Comment: @Col.Sharpnel: I done what u wrote, but still in phpinfo shows 2MB

Comment: @karthick well you have to consult wamp documentation in account of editing php.ini

Comment: ok...anyway thanks Col.Sharpnel,I will try it myself,If i upload successfully then i will tell you.

Answer (score 1):

**To upload a large file ( >5MB), I use the chuck upload method.**

```
/**
 * @param $file
 * @param $fileSize
 * @param $name
 * @return int
 */
public function chunkUpload($file, $fileSize, $applicantID, $name) {
    
    $targetFile     = 'upload/'. $name;
    $chunkSize      = 256; // chunk in bytes
    $uploadStart    = 0;

    $handle = fopen($file, "rb");
    $fp     = fopen($targetFile, 'w');

    # Start uploading
    try {
    
        while($uploadStart < $fileSize) {
        
            $contents = fread($handle, $chunkSize);
            fwrite($fp, $contents);
        
            $uploadStart += strlen($contents);
            fseek($handle, $uploadStart);
        }
    
        fclose($handle);
        fclose($fp);
        
        return 200;
        
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return 400;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in side the .htaccess file and save it.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value post_max_size 200M
php_value max_input_time 2000
```

Comment: @karthick: You must restart the webserver for this to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

To upload the larger file, one needs to change/increase the value of both post_max_size and upload_max_filesize directives from the php.ini file.

`upload_max_filesize = 200M
post_max_size = 201M`

This will increase upload limits on a single file to 200 MB, from the default of 2 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the server settings in this way...

```
memory_limit = 250M //The maximum amount of memory in bytes a script is allowed to allocate.
max_input_time = 600 //The maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to parse input data.
max_execution_time = 600 //The maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is terminated.

post_max_size = 200M //The maximum size in bytes of data that can be posted with the POST method. Typically, should be larger than upload_max_filesize and smaller than memory_limit.
upload_max_filesize = 100M //The maximum size in bytes of an uploaded file.
```

Answer (score -2):

Try setting it with within PHP script (on top)..

```
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "255M");
ini_set("post_max_size, "256M");
```

Comment: it won't work because it is set too late. PHP script do not handle upload itself. It is being actually called only after upload gets finished.

Comment: @Efazati, `Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess or httpd.conf` in > 4.2.3, I didn't know that. Thanks. @Col. Shrapnel, I guess you are right.