# Which PHP Ini file does my WAMP webpage uses?

Tags: php, wamp, ini

I just ran a search for PHP.ini file in my "C:\WAMP" server and gosh! there's so many PHP.ini files!

How do you know which of the ini files are being used by the webpage?

Thanks you for any response

Comment: `phpinfo();` knows all. Or, if you're on PHP > 5.2, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can find it in phpinfo() output

create file info.php

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

and call it from web server

[image: phpinfo ini file]