# Failing to upload large files

Tags: php, file-upload

`$_FILES` array is empty when file size is bigger than 7.5MB (more or less). 
The same code is working perfectly on my own server (`localhost`).

My `php.ini`:

```
max_execution_time = 900
max_input_time = 900
post_max_size = 40M 
upload_max_filesize = 20M
memory_limit = 128M
```

Any idea? I'm going mad... thanks!!!

Comment: refer to here.. i believe it is solved..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580187/upload-large-file-in-php

Comment: php setting for max file size can be trumped by your host's apache configuration. Might be worth looking there as well

Comment: @myfriday13 nothing new... but thanks for the info

Comment: @Orangepill in this case... i must talk with my hosting provider?

Comment: @user2559342 Would probably be the easiest.. just ask if they have any setting in place that would prevent you from uploading files bigger than 10MB

Comment: @Orangepill ok... i´m going to question it to my hosting provider. I will come again when i have a reply, thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Change the below settings in php.ini

```
post_max_size = 100M 
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

Maximum file size will be 100 MB if you change as above. Depending on your file size adjust the php.ini.

## Important

When you upload large file you will have consider connection time out too. Which is below

```
max_execution_time = 100
```

php.ini is depends on your environment. [Read more](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.php), [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580187/upload-large-file-in-php)

Comment: Same problem with the configuration that you suggested.
phpinfo() returns the correct values for this variables (so php.ini configuration is being read). Thanks again.