# Cannot upload images with more than 2000px height

Tags: php, html, image-uploading, image-upload

i'm creating a simple content management system for a website and i want to upload two images one is a thumbnail and the other is something like 1920 x 5036 px .
I have this:

HTML (upload.html):

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>Pictures:
        <input type="file" name="img[]" />
        <input type="file" name="img[]" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </p>
</form>
```

PHP (upload.php) :

```
$uploaddir = 'images/';
foreach ($_FILES["img"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["img"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "images/$name");
    }
}
```

php.ini:

> memory_limit=500M
>   max_input_time=300
>   post_max_size=40M
>   upload_max_filesize=10M
>   max_file_uploads=10

The first image i'm uploading have the next specs: 

name: project02_thumb

1900 x 1307 px

1.69 MB


That image get's uploaded, and moving to the right folder.


The Second image specs:

name: project02

1920 x 5036 px

3.19 MB

> The second image never gets uploaded. What can i do more?

i dont get any error on the screen.

> **Solution**

The problem was not from the high resolution images.

I had to change **upload_max_filesize** and **post_max_size** to **40M**
in ALL PHP.INI files.

with xampp v3.2.2 

in C:\xampp\php there are 3 files with php.ini name.

php.ini

php.ini-development

php.ini-production

Comment: Are you using Wamp server?

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: Is your upload speed fast enough? Isn't your upload stopped by max_execution_time?

Comment: Upload the second image(project02) only and check the image has uploaded or not.

Comment: @Jens no im using xampp v3.2.2

Comment: @Autista_z it's a localserver.

Comment: @CarlosPinho Maybe solutions and tips in this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580187/upload-large-file-in-php will fix your problem?

Comment: @Jens it looks like it is, i have tested an image with this specs: 849 x 3413 px and 1.08MB and it worked! i will test what is in your like thank you. i was thinking my problem was the resolutions of the image

Comment: @CarlosPinho Good to hear it works :)

Comment: @Jens Thank you one more time, up in the post i have the solution! :D

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Form:**

```
<input name="files[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

**PHP Script:**

```
set_time_limit(0);

error_reporting(E_ALL); //testing purpose

$total = count($_FILES['files']['name']); //count files

for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) { //loop each file

  $tmp_loc = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i]; //get temp path


  if ($tmp_loc!= ""){

    $new_loc = "./<<directory>>/" . $_FILES['files']['name'][$i]; //setup new location


    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_loc, $new_loc)) //move file temp dir to new location

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It does the same as the script that im using. but thank you!

Comment: review phpinfo and tell us what's your server's max execution time ?

Answer (score 0):

make  max_input_time=-1 i.e make time limit more

Comment: can u just print ($_FILES["img"]["error"]);exit;  what kind of error you are getting when u upload that image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's `max_execution_time`
This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is terminated by the parser.
The defaultvalue is set by `30`

Comment: I already changed to "max_execution_time=300", i forgot to refer that.